# How to recover deleted data from SQL server table?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I accidentaly ran a delete command against all data from table with a wrong command.

I am using SQL Server 2017.

Is there a way that could help me recover the lost data?

Comment: Did you commit the changes? If not, you can issue a `rollback;` command. If yes, I hope that you have a backup of your database...

Comment: Do you have back ups..? If not, you're effectively out of luck.

Comment: Hopefully you have a backup.

Comment: If you don't have a back up, then learn from your mistake, and start taking **regular** backups. This is but one reason of many on *why* backups are so important.